# FFServer streaming "issues"

Tags: webcam, streaming-video

I'm hoping to stream a webcam to browsers from my Pi using ffserver.

I've seen a number of similar tutorials such as [this one](http://sirlagz.net/2013/01/07/how-to-stream-a-webcam-from-the-raspberry-pi-part-3/). They all say I need to compile it because the default version has "streaming issues".

- What are these "issues"?
- Is it still true for the version I would get from aptitude today?

Thanks

Comment: [I wrote a blog on how to stream video pretty well from the Pi](http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/live-video-stream-from-raspberry-pi.html)

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg would seg fault when trying to stream.

You could try and apt-get ffmpeg and see if it works now.
Or use libavconv - I think that's what it's called - which is a ffmpeg fork.